# How to display only one block in custom page using tpl?

Tags: 7, theming

How to show only block and hide all other menus,blocks etc.,
This is my code

```
function example_menu() {
  $items['appointcal'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'example_show',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );
     return $items;
}

function example_show() {
  return theme('example_cal');
}

function example_theme() {
  return array(
    'example_cal' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'templates/examplecal'
    )
  );
}
```

My examplecal.tpl.php is

```
<div>
  <?php
    $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'example-block');
    print render($block['content']);
  ?>
</div>
```

[image]

There is need to show only region that is in red color and hide all other regions.

Comment: my example.tpl.php code is
<div>
<?php
    $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'appointment_calendar-block');
    print render($block['content']);
    ?>
</div>

Comment: Change tpl file name to "page--examplecal.tpl.php" and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Custom tpl for your page by editing **page.tpl.php**. Name should be **page--yourmenuname.tpl.php**.
In that page tpl remove all unwanted contents/regions and render your block in required region using **[block_load($module, $delta)]**[1](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/block_load/7);

```
$block = block_load('name','delta');
$output = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
print render($output);
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Can i include **page--yourmenuname.tpl.php** in mymodule folder.
Will this work?

Comment: Put **page--yourmenuname.tpl.php** in you /template folder of your active theme.

Comment: did you changed **yourmenuname**  ..?? Change to **appointcal** in your case

Comment: This answer is correct @AAjayKumarReddy You just need to name your template `page--appointcal.tpl.php` because your menu path is `/appointcal`

Comment: Just saying, this will unnecessarily process all the blocks, only to hide them later. So it is not the best in performance.

Comment: This code seems to give a PHP warning: `Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include()...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module for this purpose. It provides the same functionality as you require.

**Note**:  If you don't want to use any extra module, then it can also be done simply through block configuration setting. There are three options to control the block visibility.

Comment: I want to do it programatically , need not to use other modules

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong, the Context module is designed for tasks like this. The context module is used by over 188,000 sites and is rigorously tested, doing it programatically introduces scope for error.

Comment: Why are you going towards complexity? If you don't want to use any extra module then it can also be done simply through block configuration setting. There are three options to control the block visibility. Try this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things, depending on your requirements. (People finding this question may have different ideas what they want)

### Programmatically controlling which blocks appear on a page.

Create a custom module with [hook_block_list_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7). There you remove all those blocks that you don't want, depending on the current page.

The advantage of this is that you prevent these blocks from being rendered and processed.

### Showing a page without blocks / "decorations".

If you want a page with only the main content, and no sidebars, blocks and stuff, you can create a page callback which prints the page html directly, and then calls [drupal_exit()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21includes%21common.inc/function/calls/drupal_exit/7).

You still want to deliver a complete html page, so you need to make sure that your page callback does something like `theme('html', ..)`. This is "homework" for you to figure out :)